# How do I fix this query to get this output?

Tags: sql-server

Code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Vendors
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Invoices.VendorID 
              FROM Vendors  
              WHERE Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID)
```

Output:

```
InvoiceID   VendorID    InvoiceNumber   InvoiceDate InvoiceTotal    PaymentTotal    CreditTotal TermsID InvoiceDueDate
0 ROWS RETURNED
```

The error message I get is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   Incorrect syntax near 'VendorID'.

Comment: Where is 'Invoices' table from?

Comment: What do you mean @user7908029

Comment: **SELECT Invoices.VendorID FROM Vendors**- when you query 'Invoices' it has to be referencing an 'Invoices' table selected either after 'from' or a 'join'

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, I suspect things would go better if you had a closing paren on that subquery (`WHERE EXISTS (SELECT...)`).

Comment: Just replace "From Vendors" to "From Invoices" in subquery

Comment: Try this SELECT * FROM Vendors
                   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Invoices  
                                                   WHERE Vendors.VendorID = 
                                                       Invoices.VendorID)

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM Vendors
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Invoices.VendorID 
                  FROM Invoices
                  WHERE Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we don't generally use "*" as the column list because we should only select the columns that are actually needed. Don't practice bad habits. And since we don't have any knowledge of your schema and what you are trying to do (beyond a basic non-performing query), we must assume.

So I'll assume you have a table named Invoices and that you want to select all vendors that are associated with at least one invoice. This is how you phrase a requirement that others can understand.

```
select * from dbo.Vendors as vd
where exists (select * from dbo.Invoices as iv where vd.VendorID = iv.VendorID)
order by vd.Name;
```

However, that returns vendor information and not invoice information. Your "desired output" shows invoice information - but what exactly it represents is not known. So perhaps you can turn the above query around and select from invoices? If so, you probably don't need to join to the vendor table at all based on the output you posted.